# How to make bold a particular word inside a div in react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

Hello i have the following code:

```
getDescription = () => {
    return(
        <div className="Description">{this.props.mytext + ': ' + this.name} </div>
    )
}
```

Is there any way to bold only the following text contained in the variable this.props.mytext?
I looked at the tags  but it doesn't work in my case

Comment: If an answer works for you, you should upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<Text>` as a container for your other text components.
This is an example:

```js
...
<Text>
  <Text>This is a sentence</Text>
  <Text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}> with</Text>
  <Text> one word in bold</Text>
</Text>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append  `<strong></strong>` within the div tag and then append the text within. You can also add an inline style and set fontWeight to 1000

Comment: font weight 1000 is the same as bold